Clang-Tidy fails to analyze QT project that uses Pybind11 due to reserved 'slots' keyword
I would like to use Clang-Tidy to lint my Cmake QT project, which I develop in QTCreator. It is a C++ project that uses Pybind11 to interface with Python code.
Unfortunately, running Clang-tidy from within QTCreator on this project always fails with the following error:
C:\msys64\ucrt64\include\python3.12/object.h:352:23: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers [clang-diagnostic-error]
  352 |     PyType_Slot *slots; /* terminated by slot==0. */
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~       ^
08:56:12: Error: Failed to analyze 1 files.

Online information about this error seems sparse. But what I have dug up seems to suggest it is because Python's object.h uses a reserved keyword in the form of PyType_Slot *slots;
There is a single post suggesting that defining PYBIND11_NO_KEYWORDS can help - but I suspect this is a myth as I cannot find more than one reference to it anywhere, and searching for the keyword doesn't turn up anything in the python install directory.

It looks like consistently moving the include of Pybind11 headers before QT Headers has fixed it.
However, this also goes for the full include tree. So if A includes B, and B includes Pybind, A should include B before including any QT Headers (QObject, QProcess, QVector, etc)
